# Multithreaded program NOT using 100% CPU for expensive IEnumerables

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, ienumerable, cpu-usage

Multithreading with **IEnumerables**, which are evaluated several times parallely and are expensive to evaluate, **does not use 100% CPU**. Example is the Aggregate() function combined with Concat():

```
// Initialisation.
// Each IEnumerable<string> is made so that it takes time to evaluate it
// everytime when it is accessed.
IEnumerable<string>[] iEnumerablesArray = ...  

// The line of the question (using less than 100% CPU):
Parallel.For(0, 1000000, _ => iEnumerablesArray.Aggregate(Enumerable.Concat).ToList());
```

Question: **Why parallel code where IEnumerables are evaluated several times parallely does not use 100% CPU?** The code does not use locks or waits so this behaviour is unexpected. A full code to simulate this is at the end of the post.

---

Notes and Edits:

- *Interesting fact:* If the code 

  `Enumerable.Range(0, 1).Select(__ => GenerateLongString())` 

   of the *full code* at the end is changed to 

  `Enumerable.Range(0, 1).Select(__ => GenerateLongString()).ToArray().AsEnumerable()`,

  then initialisation takes seconds and after that CPU is used to 100% (no problem occurs)
- *Interesting fact2:* (from comment) When method `GenerateLongString()` is made less heavy on GC and more intensive on CPU, then CPU goes to 100%. So cause is connected to the implementation of this method. But, interestingly, if the current form of `GenerateLongString()` is called without IEnumerable, CPU goes to 100% also:

  `Parallel.For(0, int.MaxValue, _ => GenerateLongString());`

  So heaviness of `GenerateLongString()` is not the only problem here.
- ***Fact3:*** (from comment) Suggested [concurrency visualiser](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/profiling/concurrency-visualizer?view=vs-2017) revealed that threads spend most of their time on line

  `clr.dll!WKS::gc_heap::wait_for_gc_done`,

  waiting for GC to finish. This is happening inside `string.Concat()` of `GenerateLongString()`.
- The same behaviour is observed when running manualy multiple Task.Factory.StartNew() or Thread.Start()
- The same behaviour is observed on Win 10 and Windows Server 2012
- The same behaviour is observed on real machine and virtual machine
- Release vs. Debug does not matter.
- .Net version tested: 4.7.2

The Full Code:

```
class Program
{
    const int DATA_SIZE = 10000;
    const int IENUMERABLE_COUNT = 10000;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // initialisation - takes milliseconds
        IEnumerable<string>[] iEnumerablesArray = GenerateArrayOfIEnumerables();

        Console.WriteLine("Initialized");

        List<string> result = null;

        // =================
        // THE PROBLEM LINE:
        // =================
        // CPU usage of next line:
        //    - 40 % on 4 virtual cores processor (2 physical)
        //    - 10 - 15 % on 12 virtual cores processor
        Parallel.For(
            0, 
            int.MaxValue, 
            (i) => result = iEnumerablesArray.Aggregate(Enumerable.Concat).ToList());

        // just to be sure that Release mode would not omit some lines:
        Console.WriteLine(result);
    }

    static IEnumerable<string>[] GenerateArrayOfIEnumerables()
    {
        return Enumerable
              .Range(0, IENUMERABLE_COUNT)
              .Select(_ => Enumerable.Range(0, 1).Select(__ => GenerateLongString()))
              .ToArray();
    }

    static string GenerateLongString()
    {
        return string.Concat(Enumerable.Range(0, DATA_SIZE).Select(_ => "string_part"));
    }
}
```

Comment: Too broad. Would have to take into consideration the overall system and the scheduling of the kernel, as well as the virtualization, etc

Comment: Why do you think it should use 100% cpu?

Comment: `Parallel.For` uses lot of infrastructure stuff underneath which includes different synchronizations. These synchronizations increase probability of context switching - don't forget there are many other processes in the system with their own threads.

Comment: @Sievajet when I set both constants (DATA_IN_SHELL_COUNT, ARRAYS_TO_CONCAT_COUNT) to 10, it uses 100%. Why it does not use 100% for larger values?

Comment: @Attersson it behaves the same on Desktop with WIN 10 and on virtual machine with Windows Server 2012.

Comment: @frakon apparently the algorithm decides to use less cpu for the payload it gets... if you want to achieve 100% cpu you need to do the threading and synchronization yourself without Parallel.For

Comment: @Sievajet Doing threading without Parallel.For does not work. I tried that with direct use of Threads and the result is the same.

Comment: 10000 strings of length 1000000 consumes ~20GB of memory. Can you rule out that problem is not caused by *page faults* due to lack of free physical memory?

Comment: Interestingly, I can't reproduce the issue on my side. .NET 4.7.2, Intel Core i7 5820K (12 vcores). The initialization is quite slow, but then the `Parallel.For` uses about 95% of CPU

Comment: Actually, are you sure this is the right repro code? You indicate `initialisation - takes milliseconds`, it takes **minutes** for me

Comment: @KevinGosse My appologise, I rephrased the question meanwhile and tried to simplify it and it is not true for IEnumerable<string> ... I will put there back the initial code. Thank you for trying.

Comment: Your final method, GenerateLongString(), looks like it might exercise the GC quite a bit. Replace it with something CPU intensive but without too many allocations.

Comment: @HenkHolterman When I replaced it like you said, then it used really 100% CPU. So it could be the cause. But when I call the current form of GenerateLongString() directly in Parallel.For(), then it uses also 100%. So it is definitely part of the problem, but not alone.

Comment: @frakon If using Visual Studio, you could try using CPU profiling and/or the [concurrency visualizer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/profiling/concurrency-visualizer?view=vs-2017) and see what they throw up.

Comment: @pere57 Thank you for the concurrency visualiser. Threads spend most of the time on clr.dll!WKS::gc_heap::wait_for_gc_done.

Comment: Can somebody advise me: If I want to ask further questions to the topic for better understanding, should I a) edit the original question b) open new question c) ask here in comment d) something else? Thank you.

Comment: "If I want to ask further questions" - make sure they are on topic. This one wasn't received too positively. SO is not a tutorial site. This sort of question (experimentation) is not perse off topic but do research it well first.

Comment: Well, the threads blocked on `wait_for_gc_done` seem to confirm @HenkHolterman's hypothesis. You should try to reduce allocations in your code, and activate server gc to fully use your CPU during garbage collections https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/file-schema/runtime/gcserver-element

Comment: @KevinGosse I have tried <gcServer enabled="true"> and not only program uses 100% CPU, but runs 5x faster (no exageration). Thank you very much. Don't you want to post it as answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fact that your threads are blocked on `clr.dll!WKS::gc_heap::wait_for_gc_done` shows that the garbage collector is the bottleneck of your application. As much as possible, you should try to limit the number of heap allocations in your program, to put less stress on the gc.

That said, there is another way to speed-up things. Per default, on desktop, the GC is configured to use limited resources on the computer (to avoid slowing down other applications). If you want to fully use the resources available, then you can [activate server GC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/file-schema/runtime/gcserver-element). This mode assumes that your application is the most important thing running on the computer. It will provide a significant performance boost, but use a lot more CPU and memory.

Comment: I think the proper advice is to use StringBuilder, String.Concat() generates too much garbage.

Comment: @HansPassant `String.Concat(IEnumerable)` does rely on StringBuilder. But since the length and number of strings is known beforehand, I suppose it should be possible to allocate a StringBuilder with the right size to save a bunch of allocations. In any case, there are many possible optimizations in this sample, but I don't know if it's the "real" code that OP tries to run or just a repro

Comment: @HansPassant The real code does not have String.Concat(), but it has many operations with IEnumerables (like GroupBy, OrderBy, etc.). The repro code is just the shortest code, which I managed to write and which had the same problem as original code.